# SAS wrong sum after summary

Tags: sql, sas, zos

I have a Table with 575965 rows.
Column "Ergebnisdaten" has Format 20.2

If i submit the following:

```
 proc sql noprint;
  create table test as 
  select 
    Ergebnisdaten, 
    Ergebnisdaten*100 as euro format 20.4, 
    Ergebnisdaten*10000 as erg format 32.4,
    floor(Ergebnisdaten*10000) as floor format 20.4,
  floor(Ergebnisdaten*100)/100 as floor2 format 20.4
  from &source_lib..&source_table.;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
  select 
    sum(Ergebnisdaten) format=32.4, 
    sum(euro) format=32.4, 
    sum(erg) format=32.4, 
    sum(floor) format=32.4,
    sum(floor2) format=32.4
    into :sum_ges, :sum_euro, :sum_erg, :sum_floor, :sum_floor2
    from test;
 quit;

 %put Summe: &sum_ges.;  
 %put Summe: &sum_euro.;  
 %put Summe: &sum_erg.;  
 %put Summe: &sum_floor.;  
 %put Summe: &sum_floor2.;
```

I get 5 different values:

```
380   %put Summe: &sum_ges.;

Summe:                 24507249859.0368

381   %put Summe: &sum_euro.;

Summe:               2450724985904.0000

382   %put Summe: &sum_erg.;

Summe:             245072498590400.0000

383   %put Summe: &sum_floor.;

Summe:             245072498562056.0000

384   %put Summe: &sum_floor2.;

Summe:                 24507249656.2654
```

1. How can I sum the table and get the right value (24507249859.04) in the Format 20.4?
2. If I start the same program o zOS I get  24507249858.98. How can I get the same value as calculated on Win/Unix?

Comment: Are you using the same source dataset in all 3 environments? If not, is the summed variable set to numeric length 8 in all of them?

Comment: Note that IBM mainframes use a different floating point representation than Windows/Unix machines. So you will see minor differences in fractional numbers that cannot be exactly represented as binary numbers.  Also how did you transfer the numbers? What is displayed will not match what is actually stored. So if you printed the numbers using 20.2 format and then read them back in your end up with different values.

Comment: Did you try rounding the numbers?  `sum(round(Ergebnisdaten,0.01))`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably impossible to tell for sure without seeing the actual data, but my feeling is you're running into the problem of numeric precision with floating point numbers.

Since numbers are stored in binary on computers, anything not perfectly representable in binary can cause small differences.  Since base 10 (Decimal) has 2 and 5 as factors, while binary only has 2, you can see where you can't perfectly represent things.

For example, in decimal the fraction 1/3 is not perfectly representable:

```
0.33333333333333
```

This is particularly a problem adding numbers up, as you're asking SAS to do above.  For example:

```
1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1
```

but

```
.33333333333333 + .33333333333333 + .33333333333333 = .99999999999999
```

assuming you have a limited storage space, which computers do.

Usually, this isn't a problem.  Computers also have limited storage space for the result, and that tends to mean that you get the right answer, most of the time.  But - not all of the time.

This is compounded by the fact that you're inching up to the maximum precision possible in a two byte (double) floating point number.  As discussed [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695157.htm#a000695158), you can see that the maximum floating point number on an IEEE system (Unix, Windows) is going to be 52 bits - around 4*10^15 - 16 total digits.  You're getting close to that, and so that means that the usual rounding/fuzzing things that the computer does to pretend an integer is actually an integer (it's not, often) will not work quite the way you'd want them to, because you're using nearly the whole two bytes.

That's also why you're probably having format issues.  You're seeing the little bits of floating point inaccuracy - because you need all those digits.  Normally using BEST12. or BEST8. will hide all of that mess, but 32.4 or 20.2 show the full floating point number (Anything over 12 will likely have some issues, really).

As far as how you can deal with it - well, you may not be able to.  Rounding should fix it, visually, as long as the rounded number can be stored more-or-less fully.  Your actual number *can* be, if that's helpful.  Use `round(x,.01)` to get it to what you think it should be - but understand that it's possible that's not right.

---

Of course, the question you're really asking here, is why does *100 show 04.00 and not *100 show .0368?

See this:

```
data hex;
  exactN = 24507249859.04;
  almost = 24507249859.0368;
  integr = 2450724985904;
  put exactN= 32.4;
  put almost= 32.4;
  put integr= 32.4;
  put exactN= hex16.;
  put almost= hex16.;
  put integr= hex16.;

run;
```

Log follows. The first 3 are the normally displayed numbers, the second 3 are how they're stored in the computer (displayed in hex rather than binary).

```
exactN=24507249859.0400
almost=24507249859.0368
integr=2450724985904.0000
exactN=4216D2FBD30C28F6
almost=4216D2FBD30C25AF
integr=4281D4D4BCE18000
```

Notice that exactN and almost are close in hex representation - just the last three digits are off, as you'd expect, since the difference is near the edge of the precision (and this is little endian, of course).  But *100 is totally different.  That's because this is binary, so the fact that you multiplied by 100 isn't very interesting to the computer: the storage is totally different, since this is all in powers of 2.  If you'd multiplied by 128, you'd have a very similar hex string (but with the left hand side somewhat changed), but instead 100 ends up with a totally different number - meaning those little floating point inaccuracies are totally different for this value, and you end up with 0400 instead of 0368 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

By asking for format 20.4, you are telling SAS that you want 4 digit precision after the decimal.  You'll need to round it if you want .04 after the decimal and use 20.4 formatting.

Comment: He's asking why it shows .0368 but when multiplied by 100 shows 04.00, I think.  That's not solely because of the format.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you put:

Ergebnisdaten*10000 format 20.0 into test
and then repeat the whole procedure with at test1 table deciding by 10000 using format 20.4 again.

So first put it into one table loosing the digits and then put it in the next one.